# parameter in jsp and result in xml

Tags: php, jsp

I want to call a php link with parameter from my jsp code and retrieve the return value that is in xml format.

http://www.example.com/test.php?id=10

it return id and value in xml block

How i can get this xml in return to my jsp page and parse it to present in tabular form

id value

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: want to call a php link and retrieve a return value in that php page too?

Comment: return value is in xml

Comment: I answered as much I understood that you want to read values in xml from your php code. Your question is not very obvious may be you are new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have the following XML file, **"note.xml":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Now we want to output different information from the XML file above:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");

echo $xml->to . "<br>";
echo $xml->from . "<br>";
echo $xml->heading . "<br>";
echo $xml->body;
?>
```

Output will be: -

```
Tove
Jani
Reminder
Don't forget me this weekend!
```